# why **pointer2 can change variable a?

Tags: c, pointers

```
# include <stdio.h>
int main(){
    int *** pointer3;
    int **  pointer2;
    int *   pointer1;
    int a = 10;
    pointer1 = &a;
    pointer2 = &a;
    pointer3 = &a;
    *pointer1 = 100;
    printf("%d\n",a);

    *pointer2 = 200;
    printf("%d\n",a);

    *pointer3 = 300;
    printf("%d\n",a);

    pointer3 = &pointer2;
    pointer2 = &pointer1;

    ***pointer3 = 400;
    printf("%d\n",a);

}
```

these code confused me. we know that pointer2 is a pointer about pointer,but it's value is the address of variable 'a'. why *pointer2 can modify the value of a.the same question about pointer3? please help me, thanks a lot.

Comment: Did you not get any compiler warnings? Or did you simply ignore them? If case you didn't get any warnings you need to find out how you change your compilers warning level. If case you just ignored them there is only one thing to say: **never ignore compiler warnings**.

Answer (score 4):

This code is not valid C, so discussing any form of result from it is just guesswork. If your compiler built a binary from this code, your compiler is broken and must be replaced.

Specifically, this is not valid C:

```
pointer2 = &a;
pointer3 = &a;
```

An `int**` can't be assigned to a `int*`, nor can a `int***`.

(Constraint violation of the rules of simple assignment)

Comment: It did compile on ```gcc (GCC) 8.2.1 20181127```

Comment: @cloudyoung Make a habit out of compiling gcc with `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic-errors` or you can get binary files that are created from unknown, undocumented programming languages.

Comment: @Lundin Yes, it did. It compiled with warnings.

Comment: @Melon well, yes... It do compile and generate an executable but ... There are also 4 warnings that should **never** be ignored. With gcc 7.3.0 the program even appeared to work (i.e. the output "seemed correct"). With gcc 8.2.0 the program resulted in Segmentation fault. That's how UB may show its face.

Comment: @Melon The C standard only makes the requirement that upon programming language violation, the compiler must show a _diagnostic message_. It doesn't speak of warnings and errors. If you can't tell the difference between false positives and language standard violations, it is a good idea to always compile with `gcc -std=c11 -pedantic-errors -Wall -Wextra`. If you compile with `gcc foo.c` then you aren't compiling for the C language, but the secret gnu language.